# NSFetchedResultsController and NSOperation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsoperation

In a `UITableViewController`, I use an `NSFetchedResultsController` for my data. Everything works fine, except for when I start importing some objects in a separate thread: I use an `NSOperationQueue` in which I insert objects into my `ManagedObjectContext`. This happens in a separate view.
 The `NSFetchedResultsController` doesn't seem to like this and writes to the console:

> Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:. Attempt to create two animations for cell with userInfo (null)

Apparently it tries to fetch the new objects.

On the topic of concurrency, the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html) says something like using a `ManagedObjectContext` for each thread, but that sounds rather complicated.

I now don't know whether I should actually create my own `NSOperation` subclass, creating a `ManagedObjectContext` in it and so on, or whether it is possible to prevent the `NSFetchedResultsController` from updating for some time?

I would appreciate some help, Fabian

Comment: I'm having the same lock up ever side iOS 5 came out. Once I change an entry in my detail view, I go back to the main  table and it's locked up. My app worked fine on iOS 4. It now locks up every time the user edits a row in the table. Something new with iOS 5? What changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `NSManagedObjectContext` per thread, sorry!

It's not just the NSFetchesResultsController that will be accessing your context - coreData won't fetch some data until it's needed to your context might be accessed at any point.

However, it's only the context that you need to create on a per thread basis. Just write a method on your delegate that creates a managed object context and call that in each of your NSOperations - this will make them per thread instead of all using the same one.

The managed context on your main thread can be created with this method as well.

Comment: Do I have to somehow sync the different `ManagedObjectContext` s when I am done importing or will the `PersistentStoreCoordinator` do this?

Comment: When you call save on the managed object context it will update the underlying database and generate a NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification notification. however, I've never used that, I've always done the notifiying myself (either through a delegate or a notification of my own). You will have to watch out for passing objects between threads because that causes random crashes - pass their ids back to the main thread and get them from the main threads managed object context.

Comment: OK, I am going to code now. You might want to add this to your answer, it looks rather helpful: http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/11/using-core-data-on-multiple-threads/

Comment: Forget adding it to my answer - I'm adding it to my bookmarks!

Comment: Excuse me but did this fix your problem ? I am getting the exact same error, yet I am not multithreading.